# Sumar valores repetidos en una lista de diccionarios

Tags: python

Tengo la siguiente lista, por ejemplo

```
valores=[{codigo:1, valor:10},{codigo:2, valor: 5}, {codigo:2, valor:10}]
```

Quisiera saber si es posible sumar los valores cuyo código se repita, es decir que el resultado se vea así

```
valores=[{codigo:1, valor:10},{codigo:2, valor: 15}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No le veo mucho sentido tener diccionarios independientes con una llave:valor `"codigo":valor` único. En parte rompe el motivo para lo cual nacieron estas estructuras.

Pero bueno, ese es el requerimiento, así que propondría primero se cree un diccionario temporal, el cual acumulará todos los índices iguales:

```
temp = {}
for d in valores:
    temp[d["codigo"]] = temp.get(d["codigo"], 0) + d["valor"]
```

Documentación [dict.get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

Hasta aquí, `temp` tendrá el siguiente formato: `{1: 10, 2: 15}`

Finalmente se vuelve a convertir a *lista de diccionarios*, sobreescribiendo la variable `valores`:

```
valores = [{"codigo":k, "valor":v} for k,v in temp.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas iterar el diccionario (key, value), es decir, necesitas los índices del value, para que puedas sumar los valores de los índices anteriores y cambiar los valores en ese nuevo diccionario, puedes iterar un diccionario así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución c: pero por favor, podrías cambiar las imagenes por texto, [formateado](/help/formatting)? Aquí enumeran los motivos: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880